# String conversions in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a method which takes String argument. In some cases I want to pass int value to that method. For invoking that method I want to convert int into String. For that I am doing the following:

```
    aMethod(""+100);
```

One more option is:

```
    aMethod(String.valueOf(100));
```

Both are correct. I don't know which is appropriate? Which gives better performance?

Mostly this is happen in GWT. In GWT for setting size of panels and widgets I want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're mostly using it in GWT, I'd go with the ""+ method, since it's the neatest looking, and it's going to end up converted to javascript anyway, where there is no such thing as a StringBuilder.

Please don't hurt me Skeet Fanboys ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using `+` on strings creates multiple string instances, so using `valueOf` is probably a bit more performant.

Comment: and as the Jon Skeet article points out, valueOf(foo) protects you in any future refactoring should the primitive's type need to be changed... Integer.toString(foo) does not provide this protection.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd use Integer.toString(int) or String.valueOf(int). They both return the same thing, and probably have identical implementations. Integer.toString(int) is a little easier to read at a glance though, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that this:

```
aMethod(""+100);
```

turns into this by the compiler:

```
aMethod(new StringBuilder("").append(String.valueOf(100)).toString());
```

So the option of calling the String.valueOf directly is probably the better choice.  You could always compile them and compare the bytecode to see for sure.